# TS2339 Property 'Provider' does not exist on type 'boolean'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this error in Typescript:

> Property 'Provider' does not exist on type 'boolean'.  TS2339

new error when I try to just import userContext and do console.log:

```
×
ReferenceError: any is not defined
Module.<anonymous>
src/UserContext.js:3
  1 | import { createContext } from 'react';
  2 | 
> 3 | export const UserContext = createContext<any>("")
```

I'm a beginner in Typescript, I have tried commenting the variables with the booleans but it keeps giving the same error could it be can't do the conditional on the router?

app.tsx

````
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { v4 as uuid } from "uuid";
import "./App.css";
import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Admin from "./pages/Admin";
import Login from "./pages/Login";

import { UserContext } from "./UserContext";

function App() {

const id: string = uuid();

  const [user, setUser] = useState<string>("");
  const [showSnack, setShowSnack] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const [isReqGrams, setIsReqGrams] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [itemEdit, setItemEdit] = useState<string>("");

  const [arrFoods, setArrFoods] = useState<any>([]);

  const [inputProt, setInputProt] = useState<number>(100);
  const [inputLip, setInputLip] = useState<number>(78);
  const [inputCarb, setInputCarb] = useState<number>(225);

  const [inputProtPerc, setInputProtPerc] = useState<number>(20);
  const [inputLipPerc, setInputLipPerc] = useState<number>(35);
  const [inputCarbPerc, setInputCarbPerc] = useState<number>(45);

  return (
    <UserContext.Provider
      value={{
        arrFoods,
        setArrFoods,
        inputProt,
        setInputProt,
        inputLip,
        setInputLip,
        inputCarb,
        setInputCarb,
        inputProtPerc,
        setInputProtPerc,
        inputLipPerc,
        setInputLipPerc,
        inputCarbPerc,
        setInputCarbPerc,
        columns,
        setColumns,
        foodDatabase,
        setFoodDatabase,
        showSnack,
        setShowSnack,
        isReqGrams,
        setIsReqGrams,
        itemEdit,
        setItemEdit,
        user,
        setUser,
      }}
    >
      <div className="container">
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            {user ? (
              <Route exact path="/" component={Home}></Route>
            ) : (
              <Route exact path="/" component={Login}></Route>
            )}

            <Route path="/admin" component={Admin}></Route>
            <Route path="/login" component={Login}></Route>
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </div>
    </UserContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;


```

UserContext.js
```
import { createContext } from 'react';

export const UserContext = createContext<any>("");

```

tsconfig.json
```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```
````

Comment: How do you import `UserContext`?

Comment: I just tried to re-create this setup in codesandbox - no compile error. [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-newton-nsegh?file=/src/UserContext.ts)

Comment: Thank you very much guys, I don't know what could be happening ... I have added my configuration and imports to the post

Comment: Have you had `UserContext` defined as `boolean` before? Try clean build ( `tsc --build --clean`)

Comment: Thank Nadia, In codesandbox everything works fine ... I have tried to create the project from scratch but it keeps giving the same error

Comment: Ok, let's try the good old log then. What do you get when you try to `console.log(UserContext)`?

Comment: Hi, I have new error when I try to just import userContext and do console.log: ReferenceError: any is not defined (see the post)